# How to get number of working days in Informix between two dates

Tags: sql, informix

I need to create function in Informix that calculates number of working days in between two given dates.
I have created table "prazkal" with holidays, and two Informix functions:

```
create function is_holiday(d datetime year to day)
returning boolean;
    define hcnt integer;

    if weekday(d) = 0 or weekday(d) = 6 then
        return 't';
    end if;

    ---code that check if 'd' is marked as holiday in calendar
    select count(*) into hcnt from prazkal where datpra = d;
    if hcnt > 0 then
      return 't';
    end if;

    return 'f';
end function;

create function work_days(start_d DATE, end_d DATE)
returning integer;
define new_d datetime year to day;
define count_days integer;
define i integer;
    let i = 0;

    let count_days = end_d - start_d;
    let new_d = CAST(end_d AS DATETIME YEAR TO DAY);


    while i < count_days
        let new_d = new_d - interval(1) day to day;
        if not is_holiday(new_d) then
            let i = i + 1;
        end if;
    end while


    return i;
end function;
```

Both of my functions are modified from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693287/calculate-8-working-days-in-past-in-informix).
Result of function work_days is number of days between two dates (end_d, start_d), and not number of working days. 
Where did I made error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop increments `i` until it is the number in `count_days`, so the answer will always be `count_days` (calculated very slowly).  You need a second condition `new_d > start_d` too:

```
while i < count_days and new_d > start_d
    let new_d = new_d - interval(1) day to day;
    if not is_holiday(new_d) then
        let i = i + 1;
    end if;
end while
```

The `>` is appropriate since the loop decrements and then checks `new_d`, so the last cycle tests `start_d`.